# Autofac: Add OnActivated to all registrations

Tags: c#, autofac

I need to add `.OnActivated(Initialize)` to all registrations. Below is how I do this now:

```
builder.RegisterType<A>()
    .OnActivated(Initialize);

builder.RegisterType<B>()
    .OnActivated(Initialize);

builder.RegisterType<C>()
    .OnActivated(Initialize);

void Initialize(IActivatedEventArgs<object> context)
{
    object obj = context.Instance;
    if (obj is IHasPostConstructor)        
        (obj as IHasPostConstructor).PostConstructor();        
}
```

It would be great if I could simplify it to something like:

```
builder.RegisterType<A>();
builder.RegisterType<B>();
builder.RegisterType<C>();
builder.AllRegistrations.OnActivated(Initialize);
```

Is something similar possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create your own extension method like so:

```
public static IRegistrationBuilder<T, ConcreteReflectionActivatorData, SingleRegistrationStyle>  RegisterWithInit<T>(this ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    return builder.RegisterType<T>.OnActivated(Initialize);
}
```

and then you can register like this:

```
builder.RegisterWithInit<A>();
builder.RegisterWithInit<B>();
builder.RegisterWithInit<C>();
```